# Is it possible deploying Laravel Sail developed project to Apache server?

Tags: laravel, docker, apache, laravel-sail

I’m not too familiar with the server technologies. So my question is is it ok to deploy a project developed under Laravel Sail environment (which uses Nginx as default web server i guess) to a server which runs Apache? Will it work? Should i expect any problems?

Comment: You will need to install Docker on the Apache server. Laravel Sail uses Docker under the hood. The good thing is once you have Docker installed you probably won't need anything else to deploy. I am not sure where you are hosting it but check out this from Digital Ocean https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-deploy-a-laravel-app-from-local-laravel-sail-docker-image

Comment: I use Docker locally, using my lamp container i've built with custom php version, apache, phpmyadmin, mariadb etc. And build a (non-Sail) Laravel app in this container. I can upload files via ftp to an Apache srv. For example on a shared host (I know Laravel on shared host is a bad idea but anyway). That requires no Docker on the server. If 'traditional deploying' requires Docker, that's another thing. What i mean a Laravel project which is developed under nginx-Sail can technically work when put into an Apache server? Because Sail pulls nginx as web server under the hood. Not apache.

Answer (score 3):

Laravel Sail is [not for production](https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/lsf33l/is_laravel_sail_production_ready/). It also doesn't use apache or nginx, but php's build in web server ([php artisan serve](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/runtimes/8.1/supervisord.conf#L8)). So please use your own, or have a look at [my config](https://github.com/thomasmoors/laravel-docker).

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the docker file to work with Sail and Apache for development purpose. You can take a look on [Gitlab link here](https://gitlab.com/kokyawsithu/laravel-sail-apache) to have some idea for your production environment.